# AspectJ weaving does not happen outside of gradle module

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj

I have created an annotation and an aspect in a multi module gradle project. My annotation works if I apply it to a test that lives in the same module as the aspect and annotation, but the aspect is *not* invoked if I try to use it in a different module of the same project. It is also not invoked if I try to pull my module in as a dependency for a different project and use the annotation there.

My annotation `@MyAnnotation` is a class level annotation that looks like this

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

My aspect looks like this

```
@Aspect
public class MyAnnotationAspect {
    @Before(value = "@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
    public void myPointCut(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My module's `build.gradle` looks like this

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving" version "8.0.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.19'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.19'
    implementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVersion}"
}

compileTestJava.ajc.options.aspectpath.from sourceSets.main.output
```

I suspect that aspectj's post compile weaving is not happening when I use the annotation outside this module, but it's not clear to me how I can enable this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question and the code you posted. Unfortunately, the information given does not enable me to reproduce your multi-module situation. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would be helpful. One general hint: If you want your aspect library to be effective in other modules, you need to add aspect weaving to those modules, too. Just adding a dependency will not be enough. An alternative would be load-time weaving.

Comment: Thank you for your comment -- I've tried adding the `post-compile-weaving` plugin to the other gradle modules in the project, however this does not seem to have made any difference. Perhaps I will play around with load time weaving and see if I can get that to work

Comment: If you prefer to play around rather than post a reproducer and get direct help, up to you. Good luck then.